# How can I send a command to a GNU screen session from a web front end?

Tags: php, apache, minecraft, game-development

In short: I have a game server I want to build a management app for. What I have so far:

```
$command = "echo hello";
system('screen -S minecraft -p0 -X stuff "$command"');
```

I don't know if PHP is up to this, or if my permissions are even set right.
PHP5,CentOS 6.3.

Is there a language better suited to this task, or a suggestion for making permissions work?

Comment: The error I get on running this:
`Cannot make directory '/var/run/screen': File exists`

Answer (score 0):

To send some text to a screen you have to run the command as the screen owner.

Since PHP will surely run the command as www-data user, you should try to add "**sudo -u your_user**" at the begining of your system().

Comment: I think permissions are on the right track here, but that doesn't do it. `system('whoami');` tells me that the user is apache. I've just installed sudo on this web server, it didn't have it at install. Any configuration tips out there?